# C3JS set x axis value that come from different url

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to generate a graph with an x-axis in the form calendar_week/year
and the y-axis is just some data that was measured at that Point in time.
The data is stored in a json file and when I'm generating the Chart another script will get the data from said json file.

```
var chart_k1 = c3.generate(
    {
        bindto: '#chart_k1',
        data: { url: '/json.php?data=KPI_K1_DATA', mimeType: 'json' }
    });
```

the URL will extract data from a json file and return it back to the "data section" to generate the graph.

```
//get data from json file
$jsonFile = file_get_contents("$phpDir/betterOv.json");
$json = json_decode($jsonFile, true);
$data = array("KPI_data"=>$json['data']['KPI_K1']['KPI_K1_DATA'],
"cw" => $json['data']['KPI_K1']['KPI_K1_CW']); #cw as in calendar week

// Return the Data
echo json_encode($data);
```

This is how the Json Looks like:

```
{
    "project":"proj_xyz",
    "data":
    {
        "KPI_K1":
        {
            "KPI_K1_CW"     :   ["24/16", "25/16", "26/16"],
            "KPI_K1_DATA"   :   [5, 23, 10]
        },
        "KPI_K2":
        {
            "KPI_K2_CW"     :   ["24/16", "25/16", "26/16"],
            "KPI_K2_DATA"   :   [17, 26.5, 30]
        }
    }
}
```

[the resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmFMy.png)

Now to my question,
i know that there is some way to alter the x axis with C3JS but I just can't figure out how to set the data when I'm getting it from another URL.
I eventually want to see the corresponding calendar week on the x axis.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks alot in advance!
And this is my first post here so I'm sorry if i'm not meeting every requirement for the formating:(.

Comment: Using c3js api should do the work. Check http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load